# How to prove that $x \leq y$ if $x,y$ are real numbers and $c>0$. (Hint: Use the contrapositive.)

Tags: logic

How to prove that: Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers such that $x \leq y + c$  for every $c > 0$. Prove that $x \leq y$. (Hint: Use the contrapositive.)
I am doing homework on Real Analysis and really stuck with this exercise. I hope you guys have some ideas?

Comment: You want to show that $\forall c\gt0: x\leqslant y+c\implies x\leqslant y$, what is its contrapositive?

Comment: How is this a question about [tag:logic]? Don't you think that [tag:real-analysis] would be a better tag?

Comment: You don't have to use contrapositive, assume $x>y$ then $(x-y)/2=c>0$ so $x\le y+c$ says something weird...

Comment: Yeah, i see the point when i use method of contradiction, but the thing is that i need to use contrapositive

Comment: The structure of statement is $P\implies Q$ where $P: \text{for every $c>0\;\; x\le y+c$}$ and $Q:\text{$x\le y$}$, so contrapositive is $\text{not} Q \implies \text{not} Q$. So just find negations of statements $P,Q$.

Comment: ........what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=5,\, y=3,\, c=17$. You can immediately see that the deducing $x\leqslant{y+c} \implies x \leqslant y$ is not true for any $c > 0$.